# Can we deform retract a torus to a circle?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, retraction

The fundamental group of circle is Z and the fundamental group of torus is Z×Z so that the deformation retraction is not possible.

But what is confusing to me is that I can deform retract the square I×I to I×0 which is again a circle in the quotient space. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Yes, but it won't be compatible with the gluing that gives you the torus. Observe that the boundary of the square (without gluing) is $S^1$, but the boundary of the square with gluing is $S^1\vee S^1$.

Answer (score 3):

A square is not a torus.

Yes, there is a certain *quotient* of the square which is a torus, but when you deformation retract $I \times I$ to $I \times \{0\}$ you are ignoring the quotient structure.

For starters ask yourself: those four points at the corner of the square $I \times I$ which are identified to a single point in the torus, what happens to those four points under a homotopy
$$H : (I \times I) \times [0,1] \to I \times I
$$ that one uses to verify that the projection map
$$I \times I \to I \times \{0\}
$$
is a deformation retraction?